# rails 4 namespace :: folder structure models and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, rails-api

My current application structure looks like:

[image]

An example controller looks like:

```
class Api::V1::RegisterController < Api::V1::ApiController

  def create
    @user                  = ::V1::User.new(user_params)
    @user.email_address    = params[:email_address]
    @user.age_verification = params[:age_verification]
    @user.remote_addr      = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
    @user.web_browser      = browser.name.to_s + "(" + browser.version.to_s + ")"
    @user.operating_system = browser.platform.to_s

    if @user.save
      head status: 201
    else
      render_bad_request(@user.errors.messages)
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.permit(:email_address, :remote_addr, :web_browser, :operating_system, :age_verification)
  end

end
```

An example model looks like:

```
class V1::User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :remote_addr, :web_browser,
                        :operating_system, :age_verification, :email_address

  validates :email_address, uniqueness:   { case_sensitive: false },
                            email_format: { check_mx: true }

end
```

**My primary question** here is why am I forced to use `::V1` in front of my models? Is there a better way around this or am I missing something?

Comment: Is it not working when you use models without `V1`? Cause it's common option (use models without version).

Comment: @zishe yes, I agree that should work ... sadly, it doesn't. I validated it with pry.  The model path is slightly different than the controller path so I do not think it can infer where it is.  controllers = controllers/api/vi/name.rb  and models = models/v1/name.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constant lookups search the current module scope, then move up the module nesting tree. If you just use `V1::User`, then code in `RegisterController` will look first in `Api::V1::RegisterController` for a `V1`, then, not finding one, will move up to `Api::V1`, and then up to `Api`, where it finds `V1`, so it has successfully found the constant `V1`. But `Api::V1` doesn't contain a constant named `User` (or at least not the one you are thinking of). Putting `::` in front makes the constant search start at the top of the module namespace, more or less.

As for whether there's a better way... perhaps you want to swap the levels of `V1` with `Api`? Then there would be a top-level versioning module, and `V1::Api::WhateverController` could find `User` without specifying a version. If that's what you're trying to achieve....

Comment: For more insight into constant lookup in ruby, see [Everything you ever wanted to know about constant lookup in Ruby](http://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup).

Comment: Thank you for posting.  In conclusion I ended up removing the versioned models and sticking with only the versioned controllers. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, `::V1` and `::Api::V1` are separate module objects. When you reference `V1::User` from inside `Api::V1::ApiController`, ruby will look within the *nearest* `V1` module for `User`. Since you're already inside `API::V1`, ruby then tries to reference `::Api::V1::User`. When it can't find it, ActiveSupport's autoloader kicks in and looks for `api/v1/user.rb` somewhere in the load path. Since no such file exists, the autoloader fails to find the `User` model and a `NameError` gets thrown.